# PHP - Change Text of Extracted URL from MySQL Database

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a portion of a website that simply displays data from a MySQL database in a table on the webpage. I have the php code working, but would like to adjust it. Currently my table in the database only has two columns, guideName which is just a name description and guideLink which is a URL. Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if it is possible to edit the URL when it's extracted so it's not the long URL, but a text I set. I'd also like to make it a clickable link. Here is my php code as it is now. Thanks for the help!

```
<?php
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM guides";
    
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["guideName"]. "</td><td>" . $row["guideLink"] . "</td></tr>";
}
    
echo "</table>";
    
} else {
    
    echo "0 results"; 
    
}
    
$conn->close();
    
?>
```

Comment: *"I'm wondering if it is possible to edit the URL when it's extracted so it's not the long URL, but a text I set."* Please explain.

Comment: Like instead of the long URL that its pulling directly from the database, I just want it to say "Link" or "Click Here". Just to make the table a little more clean.

Comment: Replace the text between `<a...>` and `</a>` with the text you want to appear there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the URL clickable:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["guideName"]. "</td><td><a href=\"" . $row["guideLink"] . "\">" . $row["guideName"]. "</a></td></tr>";
```

It might be easier to do your output like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <?= $row["guideName"] ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="<?= $row["guideLink"] ?>">
      <?= $row["guideName"] ?>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```